# connect to server socket running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I want to connect a Client written in Perl and running via command line to a server written in java and running in Eclipse. It don't work, it's because the server is running in Eclipse ? when I try to run the server via command line I got an error, but in eclipse it work fine

> java MultiThreadServer
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MultiThreadServer (wrong name: inet/MultiThreadServer)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a `classpath` issue.

The `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the classloader can't find the `.class` file that you're trying to use. You should set the `classpath` when executing your code.

See

- [**Classpath in Java**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)